# App crashes when attempting to parse integer from EditText

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner to programming and am working on some small project. However, I'm stuck in a place and I don't know how to tackle this.

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String inter = editText1.getText().toString();
            String interT = editText2.getText().toString();
            String NAT = editText3.getText().toString();
            String skip = editText4.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inter) && TextUtils.isEmpty(interT) && TextUtils.isEmpty(NAT))
            {
                editText1.setError("Please Fill The Field");
                editText2.setError("Please Fill The Field");
                editText3.setError("Please Fill The Field");
            }

            else
                {


                        int INTER = Integer.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
                        int INTER_T = Integer.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
                        int NATT = Integer.valueOf(editText3.getText().toString());
                        int SKIP = Integer.valueOf(editText4.getText().toString());

                        float result = (INTER / INTER_T) * 80 + (NATT / 100) * 20;

                        t.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                    }


        }
    });
```

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:525)
at com.example.iubmeritcalculator.BS_ProgramActivity$1.onClick(BS_ProgramActivity.java:70)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5052)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20162)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Hi Hamza, welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [_Minimal, Reproducible Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such that we can help you troubleshoot the problem that you're facing.

Comment: The reason why your code doesn't work is that the if-statement in your code only checks if _all three_ `EditText`s are empty. Otherwise, the code resumes to the else block. Since your code _only_ checks if _all three_ `EditText`s are empty, you can't validate that _all_ of the `EditText`s are _not_ empty (in the else block). If you want to set the error of the `EditText`s, you should use individual if-statements and set the errors accordingly.

Comment: What is "t" in the end ?

Comment: TextView variable to display result

Comment: Set in properties numeric for editfields so you can check if there numbers entered

Comment: Every EditText inputType is numeric

Comment: Use editText1.getText().toString().trim() and follow for other editText2  and so on and try to run app.

Comment: Every-time in log-cat it appears Invalid int: "" at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334) at

Answer (score 2):

in condition you must have to check the value of skip "skip" wether it is null or not.
App crash because "inter" "interT" and "NAT" value is not null but when "skip" value is null you are converting empty string to int.

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(inter) && TextUtils.isEmpty(interT) && TextUtils.isEmpty(NAT) && TextUtils.isEmpty(skip))
```

so i think this will fix your issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this condition is wrong. To be true all of 3 conditions must be true.

`if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inter) && TextUtils.isEmpty(interT) && TextUtils.isEmpty(NAT))`

So if one of them is empty is it goes to `else` branch your app crashes because of the one of them is empty.

```
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(inter) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(interT) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(NAT)) {
        int INTER = Integer.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
        int INTER_T = Integer.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
        int NATT = Integer.valueOf(editText3.getText().toString());
        int SKIP = Integer.valueOf(editText4.getText().toString());

        float result = (INTER / INTER_T) * 80 + (NATT / 100) * 20;

        t.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inter)) {
        editText1.setError("Please Fill The Field");
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(interT)) {
        editText2.setError("Please Fill The Field");
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(NAT)) {
        editText3.setError("Please Fill The Field");
    }
```